# how to configure the client id for a free fusion table

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-fusion-tables

I created a map with fusion tables and would like to make it visible only through my website

I created a Client ID for web application with Oauth and copied the id on the map but I can not make it work

if i try to open the map from my site, it opens a blank map without markers 
What did I do wrong?

can you help me find the error?

thanks

I apologize for my English

this is the code of the page

```
    
    
    
    
    
    
    Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Fusion Tables Layer
    
    
    
    function initialize() 
    {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var italia = new google.maps.LatLng(42.147114,13.25964);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          center: italia,
          zoom: 6,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

     var campminuscolo = idcamping.value 
     var camp          = "'"  + campminuscolo   + "'"
     var camp1         = "'Nome' contains ignoring case " +  camp 

     var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
         query: {
                select: 'indirizzo', 
                from:   '1mMSBct8LQjKiZBj-BqLYhszMgjKXUJnHxlQQaSgS',
                where:  camp1                                           
                },

                options: {
                     styleId: 2,
                     templateId: 2
                          },



     styles: [{           
        markerOptions: {
        iconName: "grn_circle"
                       },                   
             }]


     });

      layer.setMap(map);




    }  

    function testenter(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {            // tasto enter  
    initialize();
    return false;        
                }
    }

    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var markersArray = [];
    var marker;

    function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;            
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        clearOverlays();
        document.getElementById("address").value = results[0]['formatted_address'];
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(8);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map            : map,
            title        : results[0]['formatted_address'],
            position    : results[0].geometry.location,
            icon        : "arrow.png",
            animation    : google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
        markersArray.push(marker);
    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
    });
    }


    function clearOverlays() {
    if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
        markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    }
    }

    function testenter1(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {            
    codeAddress();
    return false;        
    }
    }


    

    
    #avatar-panel {
    position: absolute; bottom: 17px; right: 0px; margin-left: -180px;
    width: 144px; height: 53px; z-index: 1; background-color: trasparent;
    padding: 1px; border: 0px solid #999;
    }
    



    
    

    
    input {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    background: rgb(243, 243, 243);
    width: 150px;
    left: 100px;
    padding: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is used to have user level access to your application data. If you want just your site to have access, you can use an API key and restrict use to your site's domain within the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console). You'll need to have a project and set this up as a Browser key. This [About.com](http://webdesign.about.com/od/javascript/ss/add-google-maps-to-a-web-page.htm) article can help show you the steps to get everything working in order.

An easy way to accomplish using OAuth is using [Google's Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js). You can load it up by loading the script with `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>` where `init` is the javascript function it should run when it's loaded.

I have something like the following to load Javascript API:

```
function init() {
    gapi.client.load('fusiontables', 'v1', function() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey( YOUR_API_KEY_AS_STRING );
        //Stuff to do once Fusion Tables API is loaded 
        gapi.client.fusiontables.query.sql({
            sql: "SELECT * FROM" + YOUR_TABLE_ID
        }).execute( YOUR_FUNCTION_ON_SUCCESS ); //Example
    });
    //Load other APIs as needed.
}
```

`auth` function is attached to a click event handler to a button to authorize OAuth request.

```
function auth(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    gapi.auth.authorize({
        'client_id': YOUR_BROWSER_API_KEY,
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables', //or other scope
        'immediate': false
    }, function() {
        //Execute this on successful auth like create another UI
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, 
I had already tried to use that method but I could not get it to work 

with that method I get an API Key right? 
to insert in my table of fusion tables I need a Client ID right? 

an API Key and a Client ID are the same thing? 

thanks again

Comment: @HumusSapiensIta, if you plan to view your table, API Key works. But if you need to modify, or get specific details about the table, then you will need to use OAuth for user-by-user case to handle that. To know specifically which is which, you can look through the [Fusion Table API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/fusiontables/v1/). I have something similar going on and use the [Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) for setting up the OAuth section for authorized users, and unauthorized users just use the API Key.

Comment: Updated my answer with using OAuth.

Comment: thanks again the response, 
I only require that the map was created with fusion table vensa only displayed, but only on my website 
the problem is that I do not understand how to do, once I have the API Key 

how do i talk to or interact with the id of the map API key? 
I have to edit the html file I use to view the map?

Comment: If you're using the Javascript API, then you can just use the first function to handle your site's authentication to use your Fusion Tables data. You can have `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` to run a function `initialize()` whose body contains the `google.maps.Map` created and add a `google.maps.FusionTablesLayer` which references the just-created map. All of this is documented in [Javascript API - Fusion Tables Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables).

Comment: thanks again for your patience, but I can not understand what you mean by "then you can just use the first function to handle your site's authentication to use your Fusion Tables data" for what concerns the html code I have also tried to use the one provided directly from fusion tables where there are those parts you mentioned, but it does not work and I will open an empty map

Comment: Ok, then you need to explain your requirements more clearly then. Please adjust your question to reflect this. Include what type of audience you're looking for and if they will also be able to change the data in your Fusion Table, if it's view only, or a combination of both.

Comment: I use fusion table to create a map to embed into my website 
with an html page (similar to that provided by fusion table itself) call the id of the file that shows the map. 
I would like the map you could only see through my website, so that anyone can use it and put it on other sites. 
I do not want that no one can edit the map file and the fusion table, I just want to show a map on my website. thanks for the help, I hope I explained myself

Comment: Sorry, my answer was more focused on using data in the tables for another purpose (like building your own table from your data). If you went this way, you just use your API Key from the API Console, include [Google Javascript API](https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init) file, and use the `init` function I provided as a template. Make sure your table is listed as public (but not editable by anyone). I'll create another answer which makes use of the `FusionTablesLayer` in the Maps API which is probably what you want.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm not sure I understand well, unfortunately I do not understand English very well 

I have to wait a further your answer with an example that is right for me? 
I hope I have understood right and i will whait :)

Comment: sorry, I had not seen 
I saw your code and the example and I noticed that there are some differences 
if you use the code in the map works, but if you use your no 

but other than that, then how do I apply the code to avoid that the map can be published on sites other than my own? 

thanks again

Comment: There's currently no whitelisting available for the Fusion Tables Layer of the Maps API. It's either all available publicly, or not. You cannot access the table, even with OAuth/API Key on any website unless the "Allow Downloads" is checked in your Table. [Screenshot](http://i96.photobucket.com/albums/l183/LaughDonor/FusionTablePublic_zps28aa20a6.png). So if you mark it as public, then anyone can show that data on their site, provided they know the Table ID.

Comment: I understand it can not protect it in any way then, or public or private? 
but then the APIs are usable with fusion table or not to filter out websites that can display data 

but if I enable the download it becomes possible ? 
then the map would not be viewable by other sites but anyone could download the data? 

thanks again

Comment: The wording is pretty clear. All (like downloads, API, any website viewing) or nothing.

Comment: ok, so I have to give 
I do not understand, however, what is the chance to enter a Client ID in the table 

patience ... thanks for trying to help me

Comment: I don't understand "chance to enter a Client ID in the table". Which ID are you referring to? Your API Key, or Table ID?

Comment: I refer to that field that is in fusion table > about this table > Protected map layer > set up Client ID. I do not understand the usefulness of this client id if not to somehow protect the table

Comment: The writing is on that field: "Protected Map Layer
Google Maps API for Business customers can embed maps from private tables on authorized websites." also this guide: https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2459324?hl=en

Comment: You would get the Client ID from your API Console. It's the Browser Key.

Comment: I have tried both with API Key that with Oauth Client ID but I can not get it to work 

my original question was just for this

Comment: So you have Google Maps API for Business?

Comment: from what I know if you're within certain limits, views etc. you can use the API for free but do not understand how

Comment: You're looking at a **Business API only** feature. Free doesn't have this sort of option, which is the assumption I was going with for the Tables being completely Public or completely Private. So, unless you shell out the money, these are your options.

Comment: do not think so because I have sent a request via e-mail to google and I received a reply saying that within certain limits of web traffic I could do it all for free. 
maybe I'm wrong but I seem to have understood correctly 
I thank you anyway for the help and patience 
by

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarifying in another [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578024/how-to-configure-the-client-id-for-a-free-fusion-table/22671247#comment34528393_22617003).

You can make use of adding a `FusionTablesLayer` to your map. Majority of the details can be found in their [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables). You'll need to setup a map environment beforehand, and make sure that your Fusion Table is listed as **public**.

Assuming you have an element `<div id="mapElement"></div>`:

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    // Initialize the map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapElement'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0), //Initial coordinates to center on
        zoom: 10, //Initial Zoom level
    });

    var ft = new g.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'LOCATION_COLUMN_NAME', //From the Fusion Table
            from: 'TABLE_ID' //Fusion Table ID (long string in its URL)
        },
        map: map
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

This is the same code that's reflected in their [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-simple).